# observation_persistence in global costmap

Tags: ros, global-costmap, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the equivalent variable in ROS Indigo for observation_persistence in the [costmap_2d obstacle layer](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles) that is in ROS Hydro?

I'm not finding observation_persistence in ROS Indigo

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257020/observation_persistence-in-global-costmap/) by [j_salfity](https://answers.ros.org/users/27623/j_salfity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[It's still there in Indigo](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/costmap_2d/plugins/obstacle_layer.cpp#L97). Where aren't you finding it?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2017-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [j_salfity](https://answers.ros.org/users/27623/j_salfity/) on 2017-03-27**:
First, thanks for the response, David! Yea, I'm really confused, because I saw it in the source files. I didn't see it when I listed out `rosparam get /move_base` I tried adding it to the param global_costmap/scan/observation_persistence, but didn't see it actually working. Am I lost somewhere?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2017-03-27**:
It's not a dynamic parameter, so its default value is not loaded into the parameter sever. Not sure why setting it did not work for you.

**Comment by [j_salfity](https://answers.ros.org/users/27623/j_salfity/) on 2017-03-27**:
Interesting, can you think of a test to see if its working correctly? What is the way you would set it? The way I'm testing is if the obstacles from human leg scans are being removed, but they are for sure staying in the global_costmap. Ultimately, disrupting the global planner.